# XML.toJSONObject Throws Exception Though XML is Perfectly Valid (W3C Validated)

Tags: java, android, xml, validation, rss

I am using a class to crunch XML feeds (RSS feeds like: http://www.reddit.com/r/carporn/.rss) into JSONObjects for easy processing. Normally this class works perfect for every feed I give it. Strangely, trying to use Reddit's feeds, which are perfectly valid XML per W3C validators, I get the error:

```
E/JSON exception﹕ Missing ';' in XML entity: & at character 21607
```

I threw the feed into Notepad++ and went to character 21607 and found:

```
&#34;
```

This appears to be a perfectly valid encoding for XML purposes of the double quote character: ". W3C took the same input and passed 0 warnings or errors, the XML is definitely completely valid.

So, why is XML.toJSONObject failing on valid XML? I've noted it also fails when confronted with:

```
&#39;
```

I can't believe some rookie like me is finding a bug, so what's really going on here?

Thank you!

Ultimately, I fixed this problem by doing the following HACK, I'd still like to know why this is necessary:

```
    /*
        Replaces the double-quote and single-quote values below with the actual characters
    */

    feedsRssResult = feedsRssResult.replaceAll("&#34;", "\"");
    feedsRssResult = feedsRssResult.replaceAll("&#39;", "'");
```